# Elementos se caen hacia abajo de un navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

Tengo un navbar en mi sitio. Pero el problema es que los elementos del navbar se caen hacia abajo. Osea, el icono se queda arriba y el texto abajo.

He preguntado hace unas horas aquí en StackOverFlow  como hacer que el menú hamburguesa en moviles se centre a la derecha. Antes de hacerles esas adaptaciones funcionaba bien. Ahora ya no, como les comentaba.

¡OJO!: Eso solo pasa en la versión de escritorio, por lo que stackoverflow no va a poder mostrar el bug que quiero solucionar. Creo que tendrán que copiar y pegar el código en sus navegadores.

Acá el código:

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .divform {
      height: 96.7vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
  }
  
  .lin_logo{
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
  }      

  .nav .nav_togglebars {
         display: none;
     }
     
  .form {
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 40px;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .wlogo {
      width: 300px;
  }
  
  .form input {
      font-size: 170%;
      border: 1px solid #c9c9c9; 
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 7px;
      outline: none;
      width: 300px;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .form button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 89px;
      padding-right: 89px;
      background: #0092d2;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .wlogo button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 185px;
      background: #0092d2;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .select {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .pgbutton {
      background: #007ad6;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: none;
      color: white;
  }
  
  .msg {
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 1.8rem;
      padding-left: 10px;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: msgslidein;
  }
  
  .page .text-center {
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-right: 170px;
  }
  
  .search-filterby {
      color: #006ec2;
  }
  
  @keyframes msgslidein {
      from {
        margin-top: -30px;
      }

      to {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
   }
  
  .nav  {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background: #0052a3;
      z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav .logo {
      margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
  }
  
  .nav .logo a {
      color: white;
  }

  .nav .logo, .navigation {
      list-style: none;
  }

  .nav .logo a, .navigation a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav .navigation  {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-right: 15px;
      width: auto;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  .nav .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      margin-left: 22px;
      color: white;
      transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .nav .navigation a:hover {
      color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  
  .nav .navigation .button {
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 7px;
  }
  
  .footer {
      background: #0071e0;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin-top: -17px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 15px;
  }
  
  /* *********** media queries *********** */
  @media all and (max-width: 990px) {
      .nav {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
  
      .nav .logo {
        margin: 0;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation  {
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
  }


  /* ****** ****** */
  @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
      .nav .logo {
        margin: .30em 0;
        align-self: left; /* align the logo to the left side of 'flex-container' */
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation a { 
        text-align: center; 
        padding: 8px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
      }
  
      .nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
 }
 
 .search-filterby {
     margin-top: 4px;
 }
     
 .search-filterby select {
     background: #e6e6e6;
     border: 0.5px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
     
 @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 321px) {
     .wlogo {
         width:55%;
     }
     
     .nav {
         height: 8%;
     }
     
     .nav .nav_togglebars {
         display: block;
         padding: 0;
         align-self: flex-end;
         color: white;
         margin-right: 1em;
         
     }
     
     .recursosdisp {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) !important;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    }
     
     .page {
         font-size: 65%;
     }
     
     .nav .logo {
         margin-left: 0.5em;
         width: auto;
     }
     
     .nav .navigation {
         display: none;
         margin-left: -3em;
     }
     
     .form {
         padding: 30px;
     }
     
     .form input {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100%;
     }
     
     .footer {
      height: 52px;
      margin-top: -17px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-size: 87%;
     }
     
     #loginbdy .divform {
         height: 95.1vh !important;
     }
     
     .wlogo button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 110%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 105%;
      border-radius: 7px;
      margin-top: 8px;
     }
     
     #recursos_bdy .page {
         height: 150vh !important;
     }
     
     .search-filterby {
         margin-top: 3px;
     }
     
     .search-filterby select {
         border: 0.3px solid gray;
         border-radius: 3px;
     }
     
     .page .text-center {
         margin-left: 15%;
         margin-right: 15%;
     }
     
     #ayuda_bdy .page {
         height: 290vh !important;
     }
  
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 322px) and (max-width: 549px) {
     .wlogo {
         width: 100px;
     }
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="nav" style="">
            <div class="lin_logo">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="files/audiov-logo.svg" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
                <span class="nav_togglebars">menu<i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="recursos"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i>&nbsp;Recursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="ayuda" style="margin-right: 4px"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Ayuda</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

No copié el código completo por lo que Stackoverflow tal vez no lo interprete correctamente. Adjunto imagen de como se ve el bug en mi sitio ***(pueden darle a ejecutar en pantalla completa, así si funciona)*** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues lo que compartes funciona bien.

Comment: @Lobos Como dije, no sé si mi código que tengo en la página afecta al navbar. Necesito arreglarlo urgentemente

Comment: Es necesario que el error se pueda reproducir para poder arreglarlo. Si lo que compartes es un código que funciona entonces ¿Cómo saber cuál es el problema?

Comment: @Lobos Copié el css completo, yo creo que se tiene que copiar y pegar en tu navegador para poder ver el problema.

Comment: @Lobos hay un ver pagina completa q reproduce el issue

Comment: @aloMalbarez Si, eso reproduce el error correctamente

Comment: debe estar heredando el flex column, para evitar tanto min y max en las media queries empezá desde mobile y vas subiendo ( con min-width ) o desde desktop y vas bajando ( con max-width )

Comment: Estaré probando

Comment: Dentro de `div.nav` tienes `div.lin_logo` y `ul.navigation`, pero si al div le das 100% de ancho ¿cuánto le queda al ul? pues tiende de minimizarse ul. Con que le des un 30% es suficiente para que el ul tome aire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí le puse como estilo global a los `li` un `width: 200px` y parece que eso lo arregla:

```
li{
  width: 200px;
}
```

También cambié uno de los `@media` para que los items colapsen en `max-width: 910px` y no se desencuadre:

```
@media all and (max-width: 910px) { ...
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  li{
      width: 200px;
  }
  
  .divform {
      height: 96.7vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
  }
  
  .lin_logo{
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
  }      

  .nav .nav_togglebars {
         display: none;
     }
     
  .form {
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 40px;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .wlogo {
      width: 300px;
  }
  
  .form input {
      font-size: 170%;
      border: 1px solid #c9c9c9; 
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 7px;
      outline: none;
      width: 300px;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .form button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 89px;
      padding-right: 89px;
      background: #0092d2;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .wlogo button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 185px;
      background: #0092d2;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .select {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
  }
  
  .pgbutton {
      background: #007ad6;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: none;
      color: white;
  }
  
  .msg {
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 1.8rem;
      padding-left: 10px;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: msgslidein;
  }
  
  .page .text-center {
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-right: 170px;
  }
  
  .search-filterby {
      color: #006ec2;
  }
  
  @keyframes msgslidein {
      from {
        margin-top: -30px;
      }

      to {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
   }
  
  .nav  {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background: #0052a3;
      z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav .logo {
      margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
  }
  
  .nav .logo a {
      color: white;
  }

  .nav .logo, .navigation {
      list-style: none;
  }

  .nav .logo a, .navigation a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav .navigation  {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-right: 15px;
      width: auto;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  .nav .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      margin-left: 22px;
      color: white;
      transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .nav .navigation a:hover {
      color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  
  .nav .navigation .button {
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 7px;
  }
  
  .footer {
      background: #0071e0;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin-top: -17px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 15px;
  }
  
  /* *********** media queries *********** */
  @media all and (max-width: 990px) {
      .nav {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
  
      .nav .logo {
        margin: 0;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation  {
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
  }


  /* ****** ****** */
  @media all and (max-width: 910px) {
      .nav .logo {
        margin: .30em 0;
        align-self: left; /* align the logo to the left side of 'flex-container' */
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
  
      .nav .navigation a { 
        text-align: center; 
        padding: 8px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
      }
  
      .nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
 }
 
 .search-filterby {
     margin-top: 4px;
 }
     
 .search-filterby select {
     background: #e6e6e6;
     border: 0.5px solid gray;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
     
 @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 321px) {
     .wlogo {
         width:55%;
     }
     
     .nav {
         height: 8%;
     }
     
     .nav .nav_togglebars {
         display: block;
         padding: 0;
         align-self: flex-end;
         color: white;
         margin-right: 1em;
         
     }
     
     .recursosdisp {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) !important;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    }
     
     .page {
         font-size: 65%;
     }
     
     .nav .logo {
         margin-left: 0.5em;
         width: auto;
     }
     
     .nav .navigation {
         display: none;
         margin-left: -3em;
     }
     
     .form {
         padding: 30px;
     }
     
     .form input {
      font-size: 140%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100%;
     }
     
     .footer {
      height: 52px;
      margin-top: -17px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-size: 87%;
     }
     
     #loginbdy .divform {
         height: 95.1vh !important;
     }
     
     .wlogo button[type=submit] {
      font-size: 110%;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 105%;
      border-radius: 7px;
      margin-top: 8px;
     }
     
     #recursos_bdy .page {
         height: 150vh !important;
     }
     
     .search-filterby {
         margin-top: 3px;
     }
     
     .search-filterby select {
         border: 0.3px solid gray;
         border-radius: 3px;
     }
     
     .page .text-center {
         margin-left: 15%;
         margin-right: 15%;
     }
     
     #ayuda_bdy .page {
         height: 290vh !important;
     }
  
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 322px) and (max-width: 549px) {
     .wlogo {
         width: 100px;
     }
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="nav" style="">
            <div class="lin_logo">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="files/audiov-logo.svg" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
                <span class="nav_togglebars">menu<i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="recursos"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i>&nbsp;Recursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="ayuda" style="margin-right: 4px"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Ayuda</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```